# How to stick struct objects with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

Suppose the next variable:

```
B=genvarname(strcat('B',num2str(25),''));
```

And B will be:

```
B=B25;
```

Now, I want covert "B25" in a struct object, so I did this:

```
 eval([B ' = struct([])']);
```

With that code I convert B25 (who is saved in "B") into a struct object.

Now, I want to save another struct object into B25, like this one:

```
A = 

    a1: 1
    a2: 2
    a3: 'a'
```

As you can see, A is a struct too.

Here is where I need your help, I don't know how to do something like this:

```
somefunction(B,A);
```

And stick B with A, like this:

```
B25.A=

        a1: 1
        a2: 2
        a3: 'a'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can go on with nasty evals and do:

```
eval([B '.A = A;'])
```

Which will work, but is really bad style and makes things worse by the time you use more and more variable names like `B25`.

The proper question however is, why are you using a dynamic, "numbered" variable name instead of a struct array or cell array?
If you have 25 `B`'s, things could look as easy as:

```
B(25).A = A; % using a struct-array
```

or

```
B{25}.A = A; % using a cell array
```

That's what lists in progamming languages are meant for - to avoid the need of variable names like `B1`, `B2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
A = struct('a1', 1, 'a2', 2, 'a3', 'a');
```

and

```
B = struct('a', A)
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the answer that I need, look the question please.

Comment: Then please post a proper question. It's absolutely unclear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
B=genvarname(strcat('B',num2str(25),''));
VaibleName='A';
Data= struct('a1', 1, 'a2', 2, 'a3', 'a');
eval([B strcat(['=struct(''',VaibleName,''', Data)'''])])

B25.A

ans = 

    a1: 1
    a2: 2
    a3: 'a'
```